# How do I check if an address belongs to my wallet using bitcoinJ?

Tags: transactions, wallet, address, bitcoinj, verification

I'm using bitcoinJ and I want to verify if some of the destination addresses in a transaction belongs to my wallet when I receive a amount of bitcoin. How can I verify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could check thepubkey hash in the transaction outputs

this code for exemple check if an adresse belonging to your wallet is in the output

```
    Address to= null;
        boolean tome= false;
        //from = tx.getInputs().get(0).getFromAddress();
        to=tx.getOutputs().get(0).getScriptPubKey().getToAddress(Constants.NETWORK_PARAMETERS);
tome= w.isPubKeyHashMine(from.getHash160());
        return tome;
```

Comment: What is the object `w` in snippet above?

Comment: The wallet object